# Преобразование 1234 >> [1, 2, 3, 4]. Python3

Tags: python-3.x

Имеется int число, хочу, чтобы оно стало list.

```
x = 1234
x = [int(i) for i in str(x)]
print(x)

#output
#[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

В принципе все работает, но есть ли более изящное решение?

Comment: Через деление на 10 и остатки от деления можно

Comment: @MBo, мне кажется однострочник изящнее выглядит)

Comment: Можно то же самое на функциях - `list(map(int, str(x)))`.

Comment: Можно сделать это в функциональном стиле: `res = list(map(int, str(x)))`, но ваше текущее решение более читабельное - я бы выбрал его.